# Inequality with a Shatten norm

Tags: matrices, inequality, random-variables, normed-spaces, random-matrices

Let $E_{\pi}$ denotes an expectation with respect to the normalized counting measure on $\Pi_n$, the group of all permutations of the set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$. Let $A_i, i=1, \ldots, n$ be a positive semi-definite $N\times N$ matrices. The Shatten $p$-norm is defined as
$$
\|A\|_{S{p}}=\|\sigma(A)\|_p, 1\leq p <\infty.
$$
Show that
$$
E_{\pi}\|\sum_iA_{\pi(i)}\|_{S_p}\leq \|\sum_i|A_i|\|_1,
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_1$ is a trace class norm.

Comment: Are you sure that your question is correct? If $\pi$ is a permutation on $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, then $\sum_iA_{\pi(i)}=\sum_iA_i$ is a constant matrix. Why do you need an expectation $E_{\pi}$ in this case?